# php отправить размеры изображения перед отправкой самого изображения

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Есть у меня один скрипт, который осуществляет доступ к изображениям на сервере. Коротко говоря- в GET запрос указывается путь к изображению, а скрипт проводит требуемые проверки и отправляет изображение. Однако здесь есть один момент: если загружать изображения по прямой ссылке типа site.com/image.jpg, то элемент сразу принимает соответствующие размеры, однако если использовать site.com/script.php?path=image.jpg, то элемент остается с нулевыми размерами и растягивается только тогда, когда картинка полностью загружается, а она не всегда загружается сразу. Я думаю, не стоит рассказывать о неудобствах, когда при скроллинге содержимое сайта вдруг резко перескакивает вниз.

Есть ли способ сразу отправить размеры изображения и задать их элементу? В скрипте я использую ImageMagick, может в нем есть что-то подобное? Или может все дело в браузере? Использую Opera.

Comment: Покажите, как у вас вывод изображения в браузер через script.php реализован (вопрос можно дополнить).

Comment: $image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image;exit;

Comment: Прошу прощения за эту сосиску. Сайт мне не дал ее нормально отформатировать.

Answer (score 1):

Перед выводом изображения в шаблон получайте его размеры. При рендеринге страницы изображение будет иметь правильные размеры, даже если его не удалось загрузить.

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize('путь к физическому файлу на сервере');
?>

<img src="путь, относительно web директории" style="width: <?=$size[0]?>px; height: <?=$size[1]?>px;" />
```

Еще вариант с Imagick:

```
<?php 
$image = new Imagick($image_src); 
$d = $image->getImageGeometry(); 
$w = $d['width']; 
$h = $d['height']; 
?>
```

Comment: Ну, это конечно тоже вариант, но, например, если картинка не будет найдена или будет недоступна, то скрипт может вернуть специально предопределенную картинку для этого случая, а у нее могут быть другие размеры, и таких предопределенных ситуаций несколько.

Comment: @Changeling88005553535 Все очень просто. $image_src - это путь к реальному файлу. Если картинки не существует, этот путь должен вести на картинку no_image. Далее логика отработает штатно.

Comment: Я знаю про file_exists, но вы мне предлагаете это пихать туда откуда я запрашиваю изображение? Получается, что мне нужно делать все эти проверки перед запросом к скрипту? И смысл тогда в этом скрипте?
Мне надо, чтобы при запросе к нему <strong>откуда угодно</strong> он выбирал ответное изображение, а браузер сразу же получал размеры этого ответного изображения и подстраивал элемент. Может надо дописать что-то в заголовке?

Comment: Есть две стороны вопроса. 1 - вы отдаете изображение, которое определенно должно быть на диске. В таком случае логично 1 раз записать его размеры в бд. 2 - вы отдаете изображение, которого может не быть на диске (любое), тогда придется проверять на file_exists и запрашивать размеры

Answer (score 1):

А вы пробовали FileReader? Он даже картинку сразу покажет.

```
inputFile.change(function () {
    var file = this.files[0],
    reader = new FileReader(), 
    img = $('img');
    reader.onloadend = (function (file) {
    return function () {
        img.attr('src', this.result);
    })(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

А дальше можно уже сделать. что угодно с этой картинкой и потом залить на сервер.